# How to change the order of the fields in JSON

Tags: json, node.js

**Scenario**: Consider I have a JSON documents as follows:

```
   {
     "name": "David",
     "age" : 78,
     "NoOfVisits" : 4
   }
```

Issues: I wanted to change the sequence/order of the fields in the document, say I want `age`, `NoOfVisits` & then lastly `name`.

As of now I am storing the value in temporary variable, deleting the field & recreating the same field. Since the reassignment did not work  :(

I did it in following way:

```
    temp = doc["age"];
    delete doc['age'];
    doc["age"] = temp;

    temp = doc["NoOfVisits "];
    delete doc['NoOfVisits '];
    doc["NoOfVisits"] = temp;

    temp = doc["name"];
    delete doc['name'];
    doc["name"] = temp;
```

So that I will get the desired ordered JSON document. This requirement is peculiar kind but still I want some efficient solution

**Question**: Can someone help out with efficient way to achieve the same?

Comment: Does it make any sense? Object properties in JS are not ordered.

Comment: javascript object properties are not ordered

Comment: @VisioN he is considering the order may be because of using for .. in

Comment: Straight from [the source](http://json.org/): "An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @PrasathK Who cares. Object is unordered set anyhow.

Comment: @VisioN for(var key in doc)alert(key); what comes first now...??

Comment: @PrasathK Whatever. Depends on the browser, OS, memory state, etc...

Comment: @PrasathK if you want to go for order in a for loop, you should probably rather consider an array. Objects are just unordered, and nobody can make them behave differently.

Comment: Is this the actual object that you are dealing with ? If so, then you can directly access all values like `JSONObj.name, JSONObj.age, JSONObj.NoOfVisits` Why do you want to order it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the order of fields in a javascript object predictable when looping through them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648139/is-the-order-of-fields-in-a-javascript-object-predictable-when-looping-through-t)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

May be you could change this using [`JSON.stringify()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx)

do like

```
var json = {     "name": "David",     "age" : 78,     "NoOfVisits" : 4   };
console.log(json);
//outputs - Object {name: "David", age: 78, NoOfVisits: 4}
//change order to NoOfVisits,age,name

var k = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( json, ["NoOfVisits","age","name"] , 4));
console.log(k);
//outputs - Object {NoOfVisits: 4, age: 78, name: "David"}
```

put the key order you want in an array and supply to the function. then parse the result back to json.
here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drndW/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I referenced your answer on some other answers where I didn't find a simple way to solve the similar problem I had.

Comment: this not working if the json child is object / arrays

Comment: old answer, but yes child objects seem to be empty. The trick is to also include the child object keys in the replacer array. It doesn't matter where, but the stringify() will honor the order within the child objects.

Answer (score 9):

**Objects have no specific order.**

---

### Update:

[ES3 Specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

> An ECMAScript object is an unordered collection of properties

[ES5 Specs](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4)

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.
>
> Properties of the object being enumerated may be deleted during enumeration. If a property that has not yet been visited during enumeration is deleted, then it will not be visited. If new properties are added to the object being enumerated during enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be visited in the active enumeration. A property name must not be visited more than once in any enumeration.

---

However. If you want to rely on the V8 implementations order.

Keep this in your mind.

When iterating over an Object, V8 iterates as followed

1. Numeric properties in ascending order. *(Though not guaranteed)*
2. Non-numeric properties in order of insertion.

Shown in following [example](http://jsbin.com/eyipap/1/edit)

```
var a = {c:0,1:0,0:0};

a.b = 0;
a[3] = 0;
a[2] = 0;

for(var p in a) { console.log(p)};
```

gives the output

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 3
5. b
6. c

If you want guarantee order ...

> you are forced to either use two separate arrays (one for the keys and the other for the values), or build an array of single-property objects, etc.

[(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues)

Comment: it's right, so you should not try to reorder it, even if some implementations ensure order. You 'd lose portability.

Comment: Damn this slow internet, mdn reference coming

Comment: -1: No specific order is actually an order. Node.js objects have an order, the insertion order. Browsers implement that as they want.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas actually most of the implementations preserve an order, an alphabetical for literal instantiation and the inertion order for explicit assigned properties.
The point is the standard defines it as unordered, so you shouldn't rely on the order of a specific implementation

Comment: I see a node.js tag in the question. V8 objects have an insertion order.

Answer (score 4):

ECMA-262 does not specify enumeration order. The de facto standard is to match insertion order, **which V8 also does**, but with one exception: V8 gives no guarantees on the enumeration order for array indices (i.e., a property name that can be parsed as a 32-bit unsigned integer).

Your solution is valid, it's the only way to do that in node.js, but instead of deleting and inserting new properties you can directly do:

```
var previous = {
  "name": "David",
  "age" : 78,
  "NoOfVisits" : 4
};

var o = {};
o.age = previous.age;
o.NoOfVisits = previous.NoOfVisits;
o.name = previous.name;
```

I've not tested if simply doing

```
var o = {
  age: previous.age,
  NoOfVisits: previous.NoOfVisits,
  name: previous.name
};
```

is also valid.

Comment: `var o` solution seems to be very nice... Thanks Gabriel Llamas

Answer (score 4):

Despite agreeing with all the comments and answers that JS does not define the order of the properties of an object I find myself with a somewhat similar problem to you and so I will try and answer your question:

```
  function reorder (order, obj) { 
    typeof order === 'string' && (order = order.split (/\s*,\s*/));
    return order.reduce (function (rslt, prop) {
        rslt[prop] = obj[prop];
        return rslt;   
      }, {});
  }

  reorder ("age,noOfVisits,name", {name: "David", age: 78, noOfVisits: 4});
```

It might also be used for copying or extracting a subset of properties from an object.

Note: my problem entails processing the properties in a predefined order and this function provides the basis for doing that also.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of JSON, there is no order, unlike an array where every object has an index. if you want a specific order, you will need to do something like this to turn it into an array:

```
var contact = {
 "name": "David",
 "age" : 78,
 "NoOfVisits" : 4
}
var arrcontact=[contact.age, contact.NoOfVisits, contact.name]
```

But in doing this, you are missing out on the point of JSON

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, [JavaScript object properties have **no *guaranteed*** order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)  (think of it, does it make any sense to have one?).

If you really need to have an order, you could use an array as:

```
[{"name" : "Dave"}, {"age" : 78}, {"NoOfVisits" : 4}]
```

or:

```
["Dave", 78, 4] // but here you have no idea what is happening
```

I wouldn't want to see any of these in my code. **So a better idea is to re-think what you are trying to achieve.**

Answer (score 0):

```js
let jsonArray = [{name:"David",age:78,NoOfVisits:4,otherProp:"foobar"},{name:"Joseph",age:22,NoOfVisits:16,otherProp:"foobar"}];

jsonArray = jsonArray.map(i => ({age:i.age,NoOfVisits:i.NoOfVisits,name:i.name,...i}))

console.log(jsonArray)
```

be careful to not do this inside a loop to prevent performance issues.