# Does JSON.stringify preserves order of objects in array

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a javascript object as follows

```
var myObjects ; 
for(var i = 0; i <10;i++){
    var eachObject = {"id" : i};
    myObjects .push(eachObject );
}
message = {
      "employeeDetails" : myObjects 
}
```

After this I stringify them as follows

```
JSON.stringify(message);
```

Does the above method stringifies the objects in the order they were previously?
After stringify will they be in the order 0,1,2....9 as they were previously?

Comment: What is keeping you from pulling up the JavaScript console in your web browser and trying this?

Comment: You could easily just try it out: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))`

Comment: The posted above is just dummy object . I am having huge array which contains more than 3000 objects and also I cannot say whether they are in particular order just by watching through eye as they cannot contain any index (a unique thing to identify its order)

Comment: It doesn't change anything, whether you work on large or dummy object. If test proposed above by _George Stocker_ or _Cerbrus_ gives you satisfying results, then you should achieve the same on your real object, no matter how long it it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be simply tested with a few lines of code.

Comment: There is an answer that did the job for me here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543302/1579667 which says to use the second parameter of `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: TBH I do not found this question as simple as GeorgeStocker and Cerbrus claimed to be. I also thought it is as easy as you are saying but as in it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242730/8784518) sometimes it is not a good idea to rely on JS. Specially in my case that I have to render something to the user based on the arrays order and it was a crucial part of UI. So arigato Arun Rahul for this question :heart:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is nothing in the docs that explicitly confirms that the order of array items is preserved. However, the docs state that for non-array properties, order is not guaranteed:

> Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Even if the order of array items would be preserved, I would not count on this but rather sort the items myself. After all, there will most likely be some business or presentation logic that indicates how the items should be sorted.

Comment: the fact non-array are explicitly non-ordered, implies arrays are ordered.

Comment: One could assume this yes, however it is not explicitly stated, so I would be cautious with it. It would have been great if this was mentioned in the docs.

Comment: It appears that the document has been updated. It says that order is preserved for an object - "Properties are visited using the same algorithm as Object.keys(), which has a well-defined order and is stable across implementations"

Comment: TBH I am not sure if it is really `JSON.stringify` or `socket.io-client` but I stumbled on a really weird behavior which is that I have a different oder on my server side (where I am stringifying my object) than what I get on my client side (where I do `JSON.parse`). My Object looks like this `{id: 'id', f1: [{time: 'time1'}]}` and it is happening times to time and not always. Long story short, I absolutely think you are right about not trusting JS. **DISCLAIMER: Like I said I am not sure if it has anything to do with `JSON.stringify` since other 3rd part libs are also involved.**

Answer (score 12):

For a simple way to get top level objects in a specific order from JSON.stringify() you can use:

```
const str = JSON.stringify(obj, Object.keys(obj).sort());
```

The order of the keys [] passed as the `replacer` determines the order in the resulting string.

See: https://dev.to/sidvishnoi/comment/gp71 and "sort object properties and JSON.stringify" - https://www.tfzx.net/article/499097.html

Another more rigorous approach is: https://github.com/develohpanda/json-order

And:https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-stable-stringify will output in key order. You can also use your own sort order function.

I found this after lots of Google'ing.

Comment: This will NOT sort keys of nested objects - a thing to remember.

Answer (score 5):

You can sort arrays using [sort method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

And yes stringify retains ordering.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfQB2/)

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
cars.push("ferrari");
alert(JSON.stringify(cars));
cars.sort();
alert("sorted cars" + JSON.stringify(cars));
```

Comment: In my experience, JSON.stringify sometimes DOES change the order of elements in array.

Comment: It is sorting based on the length of the key. I am using chrome. I guess there is no way to sort array of objects based on keys.

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto no, that is a coincidence.  It is sorting by ASCII order.  With all uppercase letters coming before lowercase letters.  Try changing "ferrari" to just "ferr" or change "Volvo" to "Bolvo" to see the difference in behavior.