# JSONObject toString method

Tags: javascript, java, json

I read that `JSON.stringify` in javascript does not guarantee the result string will contain the fields in the order they appear in the object. Is it safe to assume java's `toString` on `JSONObject` will do keep the order that you put keys in the object?

Comment: Try to google next time... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242441/does-json-stringify-preserves-order-of-objects-in-array

Comment: @Bucket The duplicate link is useless. OP already knows that `JSON.stringify` doesn't preserve the order. He is asking if java's `toString` has the same issue.

Comment: Java’s JSONObject class is [defined as unordered](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson library for this purpose:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder
        .serializeNulls() //comment this if you don't want nulls to show
        .setPrettyPrinting() //comment this if you don't want pretty printing
        .create();
gson.toJson(anyObject);
```

GsonBuilder class provides a good amount of flexibility when using JSON.